# Typescript's type inference, why can't the type of data be inferred?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, react-typescript

According to what I thought, data can infer the type of {list: string[] } and then use data.list , but it doesn't seem to work, and it will give an error when using it. Is there something wrong with where my code is written?

[image]

[image]

full code

```
const get = <T, C>(url: string, clearFn: (data: T) => C): Promise<C | null> =>
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    axios
      .get(url)
      .then((result) => {
        resolve(clearFn(result.data.data))
      })
      .catch(() => {
        resolve(null)
      })
  })

function getQuestionList<T = { list: string[] }, C = { list: number[] }>(): Promise<C | null> {
  return get<T, C>('acb/abc', (data): any => {
    console.log(data.list)
    return { list: [1, 2] }
  })
}
```

Comment: `T = { list: string[] }` means the type of `T` will be `{ list: string[] }` if not provided. You probably meant `T extends { list: string[] }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining the default value of your generics not what it extends !

`T = { list: string[] }` becomes `T extends { list: string[] }`.

Full function :

```
function getQuestionList<T extends { list: string[] }, C extends { list: number[] }>(): Promise<C | null> {
  return get<T, C>('acb/abc', (data): any => {
    console.log(data.list)
    return { list: [1, 2] }
  })
}
```

Comment: if optional generics are wanted, it can be both: `T extends { list: string[] } = { list: string[] } `. You just need to make sure that the overwritten T will still conform to list (which you do by the extend you mentioned).

Comment: T is Perfect！ But C will report an error.

Comment: error info : 
Type '{ list: number[]; }' is not assignable to type 'C'.
  '{ list: number[]; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'C', but 'C' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{ list: number[]; }'.

Comment: full code: 
```
function getQuestionList<T extends { list: string[] }, C extends { list: number[] }>(): Promise<C | null> {
  return get<T, C>('acb/abc', (data): C => {
    console.log(data.list)
    return { list: [1, 2] }
  })
}
```